# Python Pandas DataFrame JSON converter in List Error

Tags: python, json, list, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame where in some columns I have Json data, like this

```
 A             Ferry_values     
 Ferry          {"0": 3.4796488185359, "1": 0, "2": 0, "3": 4.4588689023021, 
              "4":0, "5":0,"6": 2.3752536905642, "7": 3.7376712853646, "8": 0}
```

Using in Python:

```
 import json
 df.ferry_values = df.ferry_values.apply(lambda x: json.loads(x).values())
```

the list in output is:

```
  [0,3.479649,4.458869, 0, 0, 0, 3.737671,2.375254,0]
```

With an error in decoding the Json File.

Could you help me in solving the problem?

Thank in advance

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the problem is that the

```
  json.loads
```

doesn't return list as ordered in Json data.

The correct script is:

```
 import json
 from collections import OrderedDict

 string = '{"1": 3.4796488185359, "2": 0, "3": 0, "4": 4.4588689023021, "5": 
             0, "6": 0,"7": 2.3752536905642, "8": 3.7376712853646, "9": 0}'

 a=json.loads(string, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict).values()
 print a
```

It works.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have json strings as values? If I recreate your example, it works fine:

```
import json

string = '{"0": 3.4796488185359, "1": 0, "2": 0, "3": 4.4588689023021, "4":0, "5":0,"6": 2.3752536905642, "7": 3.7376712853646, "8": 0}'

print(json.loads(string))

>>> {'0': 3.4796488185359,
     '1': 0,
     '2': 0,
     '3': 4.4588689023021,
     '4': 0,
     '5': 0,
     '6': 2.3752536905642,
     '7': 3.7376712853646,
     '8': 0}
```

Perhaps, you already have dictionaries in your column. However, you should get a `TypeError` then:

```
json.loads({"0": 3.4796488185359})
>>> TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'dict'
```

What error do you get?

Comment: No errors, all works fine, but the Json data are not correctly converted.

Comment: Please use : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python_online.php
to compile the code :
import json


string = '{"1": 3.4796488185359, "2": 0 , "3": 0 , "4": 4.4588689023021, "5": 0, "6": 0,"7": 2.3752536905642, "8": 3.7376712853646, "9": 0}'

print(json.loads(string).values())
As you will see the compiler will answer decoding Json with errors

Comment: Works fine for me. Just notice the difference in the `print` statements between python 2 and 3.